# IE Inline styling with Jquery

Tags: html, tags, inline, contenteditable

I use jquery to create div instances with text inside. Then i use a color picker to color the text. then i add bold and so on. When i view the HTML In IE i see the following.

```
<div><font color="#ffffff"><b> text </b></font></div>
```

How can i force IE to use inilne styling rather then using html tags. I want the browser to parse all styling as inline like this.

```
<div style="color:#ffffff; font-weight:bold;>text</div>
```

Comment: "Then I add bold."  How do you add bold?  In your code, or using some kind of rich text editor widget?  If a rich text editor, which one?

Comment: I'm using cleditor, i also tried various other editors that produced the same results. In addition, i also tried using contenteditable on a div with executing the following command for bold, document.execCommand('bold', false, true) . That still produce html tags in IE and not inline styling. I'm clueless on how to force IE to parse inline styling rather then using html tags. The only other option i see, is to write a script to parse html tags to inline styling. I don't know if one already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) you can control exactly how the styling should be done, look at the different output produced by the HTML, XHTML and Flash samples